# How to recreate service instance after delete?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-server

The service instance was deleted after running the following powershell:

```
$s = Get-SPServiceInstance <GUID of App Management Service>
$s.Delete()
```

How to recreate the service instance "`App Management Service`"? It is gone in "`Services on server`" in central admin, and nothing about "`App Management Service`" appeared running "`Get-SPserviceinstance`"...

Answer (score 1):

This is farm scoped Timer job, so you need to run the below command in order to get deleted job back.

```
$farm = Get-SPFarm
$farm.TimerService.EnsureDefaultJobs()
```

But if you have the Web app target jobs then runt he below one.

```
$w = Get-SPWebApplication https://mywebapplication
$w.EnsureDefaultJobs()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `New-SPAppManagementServiceApplication` to create a new App Management Service and `New-SPAppManagementServiceApplicationProxy`to create an App Management Service application proxy. Example:

```
$appManagementServiceApplication = New-SPAppManagementServiceApplication -Name AppManagement -DatabaseServer MyDatabaseServer -DatabaseName AppManagementDB -ApplicationPool MyServiceAppPool
 New-SPAppManagementServiceApplicationProxy -Name AppManagementProxy -UseDefaultProxyGroup -ServiceApplication $appManagementServiceApplication
```

Source: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/jj219690.aspx

Comment: New service applications can be created. But "App management Service" is missing under CA -> Application Management > Manage services on server.

Information is returned running powershell:

'Get-SPServiceApplication | Where {$_.Type -match "App Management Service"}'
Nothing is returned running powershell:

'Get-SPServiceInstance | Where {$_.Type -match "App Management Service"}'